# What is the LCCDE equation of this block diagram?

Tags: signal, math, system

[image]I can't find the LCCDE equation of this system. I try to reduce but thing will get complicated.

Comment: What is the LCCDE equation? What does the 'D' block stand for?

Comment: Linear Constant Coefficient Difference Equation(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume D is a "sample" delay making (e.g.) e[n] into e[n-1]. Use the standard form for a delay of the multiplier \$Z^{-1}\$ and just treat it like algebra i.e.

e[n-1] = e[n]\$\cdot Z^{-1}\$

The rest should be easy.